# raise JSONDecodeError(“Expecting value”, s, err.value)

Tags: python, json, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl data, however the code throws an error with `json.loads`. When I traced back to the error, I realized that the element in the loop is `None`, so `json.loads` can not run.

Is there any solution ?

Below is my code :

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()


data = []
 
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
op.add_argument('--incognito')
op.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/Desktop/Query/chromedriver.exe',options=op)
driver.get('https://www.cdiscount.com/f-1175520-MIS2008813786478.html')
link = 'https://www.cdiscount.com/f-1175520-MIS2008813786478.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
b = soup.prettify()
product_title = soup.find('title').getText()
reviews = soup.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json")
for element in reviews : 
     json_string = element.getText()
     json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
     data.append(json_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to read the JSON by accessing the `contents` of your element.

```
for element in reviews: 
     json_string = ' '.join(element.contents)
     json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
     data.append(json_dict)
```

The BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) about `getText`:

> If you only want the human-readable text inside a document or tag, you
> can use the get_text() method.
>
> ...
>
> As of Beautiful Soup version 4.9.0, when lxml or html.parser are in
> use, the contents of , , and  tags are not
> considered to be ‘text’, since those tags are not part of the
> human-visible content of the pag*

That's the reason why `getText` in your case returns an empty string and `contents` needs to be used instead.